# How return the index of row of numpy matrix where the String vector is matched?

Tags: python, numpy

I am very new with Numpy. 
I was wondering if there is a quick way to find the index of the matched row of a numpy matrix for further processing.
I have a numpy matrix [55*2] to keep 2 fields of various records. Each field can be a short/long string such as 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' or 'None' or'53472 '. So, I defined the numpy array like:

```
   HS=np.empty((len(ObjVector*11),2), dtype="<U125")
```

I read data from the source and if the fields have not been written before in numpy array, write it. otherwise, increase the number of repetition in the exact position of matched row to keep both fields and number of repetitions.

**for example
['53472 ' 'None'] is stored in HS[5,:];
now I have the same record. I want to add 2(2 times) in 5th cell of array:**

```
     array_Counter[5]=2
```

But I could not get the number 5 from the matrix.
I try to use #np.isin and #np.where, but matching was not correct or index could not be achieved.

```
   [in] Position=np.where[HS==[X,Y]]
        print("Position",Position)
        print ("value position", HS[Position,:])

  [out] Position (array([0, 0], dtype=int32), array([1, 1], dtype=int32), 
  array([0, 1], dtype=int32))
  value position [[['14:24:23.607' '10.72.0.17']
                   ['14:24:23.607' '10.72.0.17']]

  [['10.72.0.17' 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing']
   ['10.72.0.17' 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing']]

  [['14:24:23.607' '10.72.0.17']
  ['10.72.0.17' 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing']]]
```